# Burgers' PDE with a given solution (Traffic flow)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Burgers' equation:

$u_t+u u_x=0$

This solution $u(t,x)=c(1-\frac{2 \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})$ should be verified. $c$ is the maximal velocity and $\rho_0$ is the maximal vehicle density, by which the traffic comes to a standstill.

Now calculating the partial derivitives:

$u_t=-\frac{2c}{\rho_0}\rho_t(t,x)$,
$u_x=-\frac{2c}{\rho_0}\rho_x(t,x)$

Plugging the solution in the PDE:

$-\frac{2c}{\rho_0} \rho_t(t,x)-\frac{2c^2}{\rho_0} \rho_x(t,x)+\frac{4c^2}{\rho_0^2}\rho_x(t,x) \rho(t,x)=0$

Multiplying by $-\frac{\rho_0}{2c}$ yields:

$\rho_t(t,x)+\rho_x(t,x)(c-\frac{2c}{\rho_0} \rho(t,x))=0$

Now, I don't have an idea of what to do next.

Comment: (The guy's name was [Burgers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Burgers), not Burger.)

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for the remark :)

Comment: You made a mistake in putting $u_t$ and $u_x$ into the PDE. The resulting equation isn't 
$-\frac{2c}{\rho_0} \rho_t(t,x)-\frac{2c^2}{\rho_0} \rho_x(t,x)+\frac{4c^2}{\rho_0^2}\rho_x(t,x)=0$ but is :
$$-\frac{2c}{\rho_0} \rho_t(t,x)-\frac{2c^2}{\rho_0} \rho_x(t,x)+\frac{4c^2}{\rho_0^2}\rho(t,x)\rho_x(t,x)=0$$
which isn't linear. As a consequence what you finally found is of no use.

Comment: True, thanks for mentioning that, I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: OK. Now the PDE $\rho_t(t,x)+\rho_x(t,x)(c-\frac{2c}{\rho_0} \rho(t,x))=0$ is correct. Nevertheless what you are looking for is still as obscure as before because without initial and/or boundary conditions they are infinity many solutions $\rho(t,x)$. For example $\rho(t,x)=$constant satisfies the PDE (among infinity many other solutions).

Answer (score 3):

By setting $u = c \left( 1-2\rho/\rho_0\right)$, we find
$$
u_t = -2c \rho_t/\rho_0, \quad u_x = -2c \rho_x/\rho_0 .
$$
Hence, substitution in the Burgers equation $u_t + uu_x = 0$ produces
$$
\rho_t + c \left( 1-2\rho/\rho_0\right) \rho_x  = 0 \, .
$$
where multiplication by $-\rho_0/(2c)$ was performed. This equation takes the form of the Lighthill-Whitham-Richards (LWR) traffic flow model, where $\rho$ is the car density. In fact, it can be rewritten as $$
\rho_t + (\rho v)_x = 0, \qquad v = c \left( 1-\rho/\rho_0\right)
$$
where $v$ is the car velocity. It equals $c$ on empty roads ($\rho=0$), and it vanishes on saturated roads ($\rho = \rho_0$). The quantity $Q = \rho v$ is the flux of cars.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_t-uu_x=0$$
The solution on implicit form is :
$$t\,u(t,x)-x=F\big(u(t,x)\big)$$
In which $F$ is an arbitrary function.

With the specified constraint $u(t,x)=c(1-\frac{2 \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})$
$$t\,c(1-\frac{2 \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})-x=F\left(c(1-\frac{2 \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})\right)$$
Since they are infinity many functions $F$ they are infinity many solutions $\rho(t,x)$.

For example one of the simplest is with $F=C=$constant , leading to $\rho(t,x)=\frac{\rho_0}{2}\left(1-\frac{x+C}{c\,t} \right)$

Obviously this is non-sens. Probably there is something missing in the wording of the question to overcome the  indeterminancy.

Comment: Thank you. Our task is to show that the given solution $u(t,x)=c(1-\frac{2 \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})$ is valid for the Burger's equation

Comment: The velocity: $v(t,x)=c(1-\frac{ \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})$ and $u(t,x)=v(t,x)-c \frac{\rho(t,x)}{\rho_0}=c(1-\frac{2 \rho(t,x)}{\rho_0})$

Comment: On mathematical viewpoint $u = c \left( 1-2\rho/\rho_0\right)$ isn't a solution of the PDE. This is a change of variable which transforms the original PDE into another PDE.